# Limit of $(1-\cos x)^{\cot x}$ as $x\rightarrow 0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

Is the following argument valid to show that the one sided limits of the function are $+\infty$ and $0$?

If $x\rightarrow 0^-$, then we have that:
$$\ln(1-\cos(x))^{\cot(x)})=\cot(x)ln(1-\cos(x))$$
This tends to $+\infty$, and thus for $M>0$ there is some $\delta$ such that  for $0<-x<\delta$:

$$\ln(1-\cos(x))^{\cot(x)})>M$$

Because $e^x$ is strictly increasing in $\mathbb{R}$ :
$$e^{\ln(1-\cos(x))^{\cot(x)})}>e^M>M$$
$$(1-\cos x)^{\cot x}>M$$

Then, $(1-\cos x)^{\cot x}\rightarrow +\infty$ as $x\rightarrow 0^-$.

For $x\rightarrow 0^+$, $\cot(x)\ln(1-\cos(x))\rightarrow -\infty$ . Then, for any $M>0$, ther is some $\delta$ such that for $0<x<\delta$:

$$\ln(1-\cos(x))^{\cot(x)})<-M$$
$$e^{\ln(1-\cos(x))^{\cot(x)})}<e^{-M}<\frac{1}{M}$$
$$(1-\cos x)^{\cot x}<\frac{1}{M}$$

Then, $(1-\cos x)^{\cot x}\rightarrow 0$ as $x\rightarrow 0^+$.

Answer (score 1):

More simply, as $x\to 0^+$ we have

$$(1-\cos x)^{\cot x} \to (0^+)^\infty =0^+$$

and then as $x=-y\to 0^- \implies y\to 0^+$ we have

$$(1-\cos x)^{\cot x}=(1-\cos( -y))^{\cot (-y)}=\frac{1}{(1-\cos y)^{\cot y}} \to \infty$$